# Let $0 < a \le b$. Then $a^2 \le \left (\frac{2ab}{a+b} \right) ^2 \le ab \le \left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right) ^2 \le b^2$

Tags: calculus, inequality, solution-verification

In a introductory text about real analysis, in a chapter about the axioms of order (I hope this is the correct translation), I was faced with the following

**Problem:** Let $0 < a \le b$. Show that $a^2 \le \left (\frac{2ab}{a+b} \right) ^2 \le ab \le \left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right) ^2 \le b^2$. If, at any point of this chain of inequalities, we have equality, then $a = b$.

There was no solution given. I came to the following

**Solution:** The first inequality follows from

$$ \begin{align} a^2 & \le ab\\
a^2 + ab & \le 2ab \\
a(a+b) & \le 2ab \\
a & \le \frac{2ab}{a+b} \\
a^2 & \le \left( \frac{2ab}{a+b} \right) ^2 \end{align}$$

By the same reasoning, if equality holds, $a^2=ab$ implies that $a=b$.

We get the second inequality from

$$ \begin{align} 0 & \le (a-b)^2\\
0 & \le a^2 - 2ab + b^2 \\
4ab & \le a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \\
\frac{4a^2b^2}{ab} & \le (a+b)^2 \\
\frac{4a^2b^2}{(a+b)^2} & \le ab \\
\left( \frac{2ab}{a+b} \right) ^2 & \le ab \end{align}$$

an similarly for the third inequality with

$$ \begin{align} 0 & \le (a-b)^2\\
0 & \le a^2 - 2ab + b^2 \\
4ab & \le a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \\
ab & \le \frac{(a+b)^2}{4} \\
ab & \le \left( \frac{(a+b)}{2} \right) \\ \end{align}$$

In both cases, $0 = (a-b)^2$ implies that $a=b$.

Finally we have

$$ \begin{align} a & \le b \\
a + b & \le 2b \\
\frac{a+b}{2} & \le b \\
\left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right) ^2 & \le b^2 \end{align}$$

and equality directly leads to $a=b$. $\blacksquare$

I have three questions to this:

1. Is my solution correct?
2. Do I have to take additional steps for the second part of the problem, that equality implies $a=b$?
3. Are there shorter and more elegant solutions to this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi there, the question you mentioned is a restatement of the more general AM-GM-HM inequalities. Have a look at it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities.

Comment: Also the solutions you gave are fine, and you dont need additional steps to prove the equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It look quite correct for me, and the equality part is good since $a,b$ are both positive.

Just for showing a shorter (maybe) version for this by using two important but simple inequalies:

(1). $(a+b)^2 \geq 4ab$

And its variation in case of $a>0,b>0$ :

(2). $ 1 \geq \frac{4ab}{(a+b)^2}$

We have:
$$
b^2 \geq (\frac{a+b}{2})^2 \ \ (\text{because } b \geq a > 0) \\
= \frac{(a+b)^2}{4} \geq \frac{4ab}{4}=ab \ \ \ (\text{because (1) }) \\
= ab \times 1 \geq ab \times \frac{4ab}{(a+b)^2} = (\frac{2ab}{a+b})^2  \ \ \ (\text{because (2) }) \\
\geq (\frac{2ab}{b+b})^2 = a^2  \ \ \ (\text{because } b \geq a >0 )
$$

Actually, the first and the last inequalites use $a\geq b>0$, the second and third ones use HM-GM-AM-QM inequalities mentioned by @mrtechtroid.